# Marrying one's father's wife

Tags: halacha, family-members, arayot

A man is forbidden to his father's wife, even if she is not his biological mother (cf: Leviticus 18:8; Yevamot 1:3). Is this still the case after his father dies or after he divorces her? In other words, is a man prohibited to his father's widow or to his father's divorcee?

[For anybody unfamiliar with the language of such regulations, this is a technical question about prohibited sexual relationships only. I am asking this out of a desire to understand the halakha, and am offering neither approval nor censure.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch EH 15:5 states:

> אשת אביו אסורה לו מן התורה, בין שהיא אשתו מן הנשואין בין מן האירוסין, בין בחיי אביו בין כשמת אביו או גירשה.‏
>   The wife of one's father is forbidden to him biblically, whether she was his wife from *nissu'in* or *erusin*, whether one's father is alive or not or [even if] he divorced her.

Comment: TTBOMK the only biblical familial arayot that are ever later permitted is a man's wife's sister after the wife's death, and a woman's husband's brother after the childless death of the husband.